# Resample with asymmetrical timeperiods in pandas (8 months then 4 months)

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily 20 year data that I want to resample such that the data is broken up into March - October and November - February. Basically 8 month and 4 month chunks. Is there a way to do this using the resample function?

I think that the DateOffset'8MS' would resample every 8 months. Is there a way to get it to alternate 8 month then 4 month period?

I don't actually really need the data for the 4 month period so the alternative could be to just remove that data and keep it at 8MS I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't need the data for the 4 month period, the easiest way is to filter these months and then you can use `resample` on a yearly frequency or `groupby`. Assuming the index is the `DatetimeIndex`, then you can do:

```
#mask to keep months in [3, 4, ...10]
m = df.index.month.isin(range(3, 11))

#with resample for example
df[m].resample('Y').mean()

#with groupby
df[m].groupby(df.index.year[m]).mean()
```

Similar result except in index names